In Shuffle!, why did Rin choose Asa to be his girlfriend?
Just out of curiosity, why did Rin choose Asa to be his girlfriend?
Are there any significant reasons or facts?
I was originally hoping that Rin would pick either Nerine or his childhood friend, Kaede, but for some strange reason, he chose Asa. So I'm curious to know would pick her and not the other girls (Kaede, Sia, & Nerine)
I never thought he would pick Asa, because he looks like he gets really annoyed with her since the first episode.

It's based on a VN where the player gets to pick. Why the anime went for this route in the ending is anyone's guess.

That doesn't answer my question.
